# PostGIS Nearest Neighbor Search Results Out of Order?

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, nearest-neighbor

I have a Django/PostgreSQL application that shows which users are nearest a particular user.  It uses the PostGIS 2.0 KNN (K Nearest Neighbors) <-> operator in the ORDER BY clause to list the users, nearest first.  What I've found with my initial dataset is that two of the search results are out of order (all distances are measured from Los Angeles, CA):

```
Member, City, State, Distance (miles)

user1, North Las Vegas, NV, 239
user2, Phoenix, AZ, 365
user3, Provo, UT, 568
user4, Twin Falls, ID, 630
user5, Albuquerque, NM, 673
user6, Portland, OR, 828
user7, Bozeman, MT, 896
user8, Seattle, WA, 962
user9, Boulder, CO, 834       <- Out of order!
user10, Laramie, WY, 862      <- Out of order!
user11, Naperville, IL, 1756
```

The Member name is just the username column from Django's contrib.auth.models User class.  The UserAccount class which contains the geometry information is defined as follows:

```
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
    measurement_sys = models.CharField(max_length=5)  # US or Metric

    # User's home (default) and current longitude and latitude
    home_lon = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    home_lat = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    current_lon = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    current_lat = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    # GeoDjango-specific fields 
    home_point = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    current_point = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Here's the query in my Django view:

```
def members(request, template):
    """View all members of the website."""
    uid = request.session['uid']   # PK from User table

    # Get the current user's lon/lat and measurement system
    try:
        ua = UserAccount.objects.get(user_id=uid)
        lon = ua.current_lon
        lat = ua.current_lat
        measurement_sys = ua.measurement_sys
    except UserAccount.DoesNotExist as e:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('unable-to-display-members'))

    # Define the proximity query.
    if measurement_sys == 'US':
        multiplier = 0.000621371  # Convert to miles
    else:
        multiplier = 0.001  # Convert to kilometers

    query = "SELECT \
                ua.user_id, \
                au.username, \
                ua.city, \
                ua.region, \
                ST_Distance( \
                    ua.current_point::geography, \
                    ST_GeographyFromText( \
                        'SRID=4326;POINT(" \
                            + str(lon) \
                            + " " \
                            + str(lat) + \
                        ")' \
                    ) \
                )*" + str(multiplier) + " AS distance \
            FROM \
                user_account ua \
                INNER JOIN \
                auth_user au \
                ON (ua.user_id = au.id) \
            WHERE ua.user_id != %s \
            ORDER BY \
                ua.current_point::geometry \
                <-> \
                'SRID=4326;POINT(" + str(lon) + " " + str(lat) + ")'::geometry \
            LIMIT 250;"

    # Run the proximity query
    raw_queryset = UserAccount.objects.raw(query, [uid])

    # Paginate results
    user_list = [user for user in raw_queryset]
    list_size = len(list(user_list))
    paginator = Paginator(user_list, 10, 4)
    paginator._count = list_size

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, template, {'users': users})
```

Am I doing anything wrong in my query?  Can the KNN operator sometimes "hiccup" and return some results out of order?  I ask this because when I tried taking the two out-of-order records out of my table but then adding additional records for users with addresses in that are even farther away (i.e. in IL, LA, MI, NC, PA, NY and ME), all the results were in the correct order.

By the way, my inputs are located [here](http://pastebin.com/sGyiipWs).

Thanks!

Comment: That is very odd. Could you maybe post some data, so we can test?

Comment: Sure.  Here's the test data: http://pastebin.com/sGyiipWs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

Postgis has two **approximate** solutions for kNN neighbors functionality, since [September 2011](http://boundlessgeo.com/2011/09/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/):

- Using the <-> operator, you get the nearest neighbour using the centers of the bounding boxes to calculate the inter-object distances.
- Using the <#> operator, you get the nearest neighbour using the bounding boxes themselves to calculate the inter-object distances.

Your problem is, that both are approximate, so they are not perfect. So, if you want the best 250 results, you can use any of them to retrieve for example the best 1000 results and then order the same results by  ST_DISTANCE and LIMIT 250 to get the best 250 results out of those approximate 1000.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT *,ST_DISTANCE(current_point::geography, 'SRID=4326;POINT(" + str(lon) + " " + str(lat) + ")'::geography ) AS st_dist
    FROM ua
    ORDER BY current_point::geometry <-> 'SRID=4326;POINT(" + str(lon) + " " + str(lat) + ")'::geometry 
    LIMIT 1000) AS s
    ORDER BY st_dist LIMIT 250;
```

Comment: Alexandros, thanks for your comments as they gave me some other things to think about.  Unfortunately, your suggested change to the ORDER BY clause won't work.  The KNN operator "<->" only takes geometry operands.  If you try to cast both operands to geography types, you'll get "ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: geography <-> geography"  One problem I did find was that I needed to declare my home_point and current_point columns as Django PointField types rather than GeometryField types.  But even after doing that, the results were still out of order.

Comment: For what it's worth, I replaced the CO and WY user records with addresses from two different cities in CO and WY and, again, those two records were out of order.

Comment: Alexandros, that seems to have fixed the problem.  I really appreciate your help!  I had seen the article you referenced but I didn't implement its solution because it seemed to say the technique was only necessary if you're doing calculations on non-point objects such as lines and polygons.  Since my calculation was for the distance between points and the bounding boxes for points are equivalent to the points themselves, the answer would be exact.  I guess I should have tried it anyway.

Comment: @Alexandros. Well noticed Alexandros. I totally missed that.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking at the same very problem.
I was wondering if you found a better solution ?

Thanks